# Genetic algorithm based microphone array placement for optimum acoustic coverage

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to find the optimal location for the placement of the microphones. I want to reduce the no of microphones place on the given area of interest. I want to use minimum no of microphones to cover large area by using some algorithms or other wise it would take years to manually place the microphones.

I have calculated the fitness function using the viewshed analysis in ArcGIS but on the algorithm part I was unable to find much on internet.

Are there standard algorithms for choosing where to locate the microphones optimally?

Comment: On the highest mountain.

Comment: You had a tag for ArcPy but have not included a code attempt so I’ve removed it.

Comment: Microphone placement is not a standard GIS task, so standard algorithms are in short supply.

Comment: Where will i get the algorithm.?